# How to get the OutputStream of a written PDF from iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, inputstream, outputstream

I need your help in getting and storing the written PDF from iText in an `OutputStream` and then to convert it to an `InputStream`.

The code of writing the PDF is below:

```
public void  CreatePDF() throws IOException {
      try{
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);

        doc.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First PDF"));
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        table.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(table);
        doc.close();

      }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

So I am seeking your help to write that PDF in an `OutputStream` and then to convert it to `InputStream`.

I need to get the `InputStream` value so I can pass it to the line for the file download:

```
StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(InputStream, "application/pdf", "xxx.pdf");
```

Updated Jon Answer:

```
public InputStream createPdf1() throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    try {        

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
        PdfWriter writer;
            try {
                writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
            }
            doc.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First PDF"));
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        table.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(table);

        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: What is `out` in the `PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I missed one line. Please check the updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the declaration of `out` to be of type `ByteArrayOutputStream` rather than just `OutputStream`. Then you can call [`ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--) to get the bytes, and construct a `ByteArrayInputStream` wrapping that.

As an aside, I wouldn't catch `Exception` like that, and I'd use a try-with-resources statement to close the document, assuming it implements `AutoCloseable`. It's also a good idea to follow Java naming conventions. So for example, you might have:

```
public InputStream createPdf() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
    try (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50)) {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
        doc.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First PDF"));
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        table.addCell(cell);
        doc.add(table);
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I have one question and I would like your clarification on that.  I am having a line in the code where I need to pass the InputStream value: StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", "xxx.pdf"); In the stream value, I need to pass an InputStream, but in your solution, it is ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: I have updated the code with the line so it will be more clear

Comment: @99maas: Do you not understand that a `ByteArrayInputStream` *is* an `InputStream`? If you're unfamiliar with how polymorphism and inheritance work in Java, I suggest you go back to basics before proceeding further.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will check that as I am not familiar with how the InputStream & OutputStream are working

Comment: The last line is showing an error that out is not defined return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

Comment: @99maas: Are you sure you've got the code *exactly* as I've written it, with the declaration of `out` as the first line of the method?

Comment: Please check the updated post as I copied your code and I got an error in the declaration of the ByteOutputStream and I tried to fix it in Jdeveloper

Comment: @99maas: That was a typo for `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: If you had declared out in a function somewhere, how could you get to out  if you just had the PdfDocument ?

Comment: @MAkin: I strongly suspect you'd have to write the PdfDocument out again.

Comment: @jon I never figured this out, but I found a way around it.  I am using the PdfSplitter, and created a property on the splitter with a list of the streams it has created for each split document in c#